# exception error in reading from file using c++ file handling

Tags: c++, exception, file-handling

This programme takes a string (name of student) as input, generates a roll number of that student according to the number of students already present in the file. And then stores this information as a structure in that file. Further details are in comments.This code is working fine until I change any one of these ->

1. In main() function if I send 'data stud' as a reference it is working fine. But if I send it as a copy, which means making a new object of the class for writing and reading in the file every time (which is fine, isn't it?).It is giving an exception.
2. In rollGen() function, I created an object temp of class data to count the number of students whose data is already present in that file. If this object is created dynamically, the code is working. But if I create it statically, the programme is giving an exception (see comments for example).
   I want to know, why this is happening Is it some scope related thing...or whatever. Thanks in advance. Exception -

[image]

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<fstream>

    struct student
    {
        char RollNo[8];
        std::string name;
    };

    class data
    {
        student stu;
    public:
        data() {}
        //open a file for fstream in argument...mod = 0 for input mode...mod = 1 for output mode
        void openn(int mod, std::fstream* yo_fp)    
        {
            if (mod == 0)
            {
                yo_fp->open("cs.txt", std::ios::in);
            }
            else if (mod == 1)
            {
                yo_fp->open("cs.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
            }
        }
        //generates roll number of student 
        //for example if data of 3 students is already present in file then roll number of new student will be cs4
        void rollGen()
        {
            std::fstream* rg_fp = new std::fstream;
            openn(0, rg_fp);
            int i = 1;
            data* temp = new data;  
            //if I allocate temp on stack...like, 'data temp;' and then in while loop replace 'temp' with '&temp'...programm is giving exception
            //counting number of students whose data is already present in file
            while (rg_fp->read((char*)temp, sizeof(data)))
            {
                i++;
            }
            strcpy_s(stu.RollNo, "cs"); 
            std::string s = std::to_string(i);
            strcat_s(stu.RollNo, s.c_str());
            rg_fp->close();
            delete rg_fp;
        }
        //take name string as input and call roll number generation function. hence providing data to student stu struct present in this class
        void input()
        {
            std::cout << "Enter your name - ";
            getline(std::cin, stu.name);
            rollGen();
            std::cout << "your RollNo is - " << stu.RollNo << std::endl;
        }
        //printing tha data of student stu struct present in class
        void output()
       {
            std::cout << "roll no - " << stu.RollNo << std::endl;
            std::cout << "name - " << stu.name << std::endl;
        }
    };
    //write the data of class object into file after calling input() function
    //using 'data stud' in argument instead of 'data& stud' gives exception
    void write(data& stud, std::fstream* cur_fp)
    {
        stud.input();
        stud.openn(1, cur_fp);
        cur_fp->write((char*)&stud, sizeof(data));
        std::cout << std::endl;
        cur_fp->close();
    }
    //printing all elements of file one by one
    //using 'data stud' in argument instead of 'data& stud' gives exception
    void read(data& stud, std::fstream* cur_fp)
    {
        stud.openn(0, cur_fp);
        std::cout << "Data in File is - " << std::endl << std::endl;;
        while (cur_fp->read((char*)&stud, sizeof(data)))
        {
            stud.output();
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        cur_fp->close();
        std::cin.get();
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::fstream *fp = new std::fstream;
        data stud;
        write(stud, fp);
        write(stud, fp);
        read(stud, fp);
        delete fp;
    }
```

Comment: How long names do you use? Could you be entering a too long name, causing overwrite of the end of the char array RollNo?

Comment: @ErikAlapää I am using 3 char long names without blank spaces.

Comment: You have multiple problems in that code which I can see on a quick look - not least of which is that it wouldn't compile, let alone throw exceptions, because `strcpy_s()` and `strcat_s()` are called with two arguments and actually require three.   Since the functions in your code interact quite a bit, and you're using pointers unnecessarily, there is plenty of scope for problems.   You need to apply effort to reduce the amount of extraneous code, and isolate the problem (or problems), otherwise nobody else has a fighting chance of helping you.  Voting to close accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `data` contain a member field `sudent stu` what contains  a member field`std::string name` which stores content on the heap so by reading `data` objects from file `rg_fp->read((char*)temp, sizeof(data))` you essentially fill string with invalid pointers leading to all sorts of undefined behavior. Note that writing it to file like `cur_fp->write((char*)&stud, sizeof(data));` is not working either because string content is not written. You should implement proper [de] serialization storing content of each class field one by one.